# Convert interleaved video into separate left/right videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stereo, 3d

I'm trying to make two files from video recorded on 3d camera and can't find how can I separate one video onto two.

`ffprobe video.m2ts` gives me

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'video.m2ts': Duration: 00:00:08.32, start: 1.000033, bitrate: 26724 kb/s   Program 1 
Stream #0.0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0.1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
Stream #0.2[0x1200]: Subtitle: pgssub
Stream #0.3[0x1012]: Data: HDMV / 0x564D4448 Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
```

So I think that all I need to extract (from `Stream #0.0` 50fps) odd frames to one video and even frames to another to get 25fps on each video.

Current command looks like

`ffmpeg -i "video.m2ts" -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -y "out.mov"`